# SQL help for inner query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, toad

Sorry for repost but this will help you understand the scnario better-
For each member, there can be two types of addresses (mail and legal- based on two diff indicators). My goal is extract both the adress and show them in one column for each member id.

**TABLE1**

```
Address_key(PK)  Country  City      PostCode
1                UK       London    1111
2                US       New York  2222
3                Spain    Madrid    3333
4                France   Paris     4444
5                Swiss    Munich    5555
```

**Table 2**

```
Member Key(PK)   Memebr ID
1                1
2                2
3                3
4                2
```

**Table3**

```
Address Key   Member Key    Mail Ind   Legal Ind
1             1             Y          N
2             1             N          Y
3             2             Y          Y
4             4             N          Y
5             4             Y          N
```

My goal is to get the mail address(based on mail ind) and legal adress(based on legal ind) for each member id. 
SO my output should be -

```
Member Key   Member ID   Country   City    Postcode   Legal Country   Legal City   Legal Postcode
1            1           UK        London  1111       US              New York     2222
2            2           Spain     Madrid  3333       Spain           Madrid       3333         
4            2           Swiss     Munich  5555       France          Paris        4444
```

Can anyone help how to achieve this ? I am using oracle 10m toad 9.0
Which is better to use: Inner query or simple join ?

Comment: where's your original post?

Comment: What is oracle 10m? Did you mean to say oracle 10G?

Comment: Why did you repost instead of editing your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22906364/266304), as the [help centre suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below? With your column naming i'm a little confused with Table2 Member Key(PK) , Memebr ID and what their relationship is to Table 3 Member ID. My best guess is below:

```
Select [Member Key], t2.[Member Id], t1.*
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3 on t3.[Member Key] = t2.[Member Id]
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 on t1.[Address Key] = t3.[Address Key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two types of addresses, you could join twice to TABLE3, once for the Mailing address and next for the legal address.

```
select T2.Member_Key, T2.Member_id
       ,coalesce(T1A.Country,''), coalesce(T1A.City,''), coalesce(T1A.PostCode,'')
       ,coalesce(T1B.Country,''), coalesce(T1B.City,''), coalesce(T1B.PostCode,'')
from Table2 T2
left join Table3 T3A on T2.Member_Key=T3A.Member_Key and T3A.Mail_Ind='Y'
left join Table1 T1A on T3A.Address_key = T1A.Address_Key
left join Table3 T3B on T2.Member_Key=T3B.Member_Key and T3B.Legal_Ind='Y'
left join Table1 T1B on T3B.Address_key = T1B.Address_Key
```

Another way would be to join once and use a CASE expression, thus:

```
select T2.Member_Key, T2.Member_id
       ,max(coalesce(CASE T3.Mail_Ind='Y'  then T1.Country Else '' End,''))
       , ... etc.
       ,max(coalesce(CASE T3.Legal_Ind='Y' then T1.Country Else '' End,''))
       , ... etc.
from Table2 T2
left join Table3 T3 on T2.Member_Key=T3.Member_Key 
left join Table1 T1A on T3.Address_key = T1.Address_Key
group by Member_Key, Member_id
```